# .htaccess rewrite rule not working for me

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up some pretty URLs so

`http://www.foo.com/results/2014`

calls

`http://www.foo.com/results/index.php?year=2014`

Where '2014' could really be any string (and I will do the appropriate error-handling should I get inappropriate input).

What I'm getting, however, is that `http://www.foo.com/results/` works fine but anything after the trailing slash returns a 404 error.

Below are the contents of my .htaccess file.  Could someone please point out my error?

Thanks in advance!

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/results/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/?$ /results/index.php?year=$1
```

Comment: Is `/results/` a physical directory? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Yes `/results/` is a directory, inside which are both the .htaccess and index.php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way inside `/results/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /results/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$  index.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Reason why your rule didn't work:

1. You can only match URI pattern relative from current directory. So if you're already in `results/` folder and URI is `/results/foo` then matched URI will be `foo` in `RewriteRule`
2. No use of `RewriteBase`

Comment: This works, but doesn't seem to work if I remove the 'www' in the URL.  If I do, it redirects to `www.foo.com/$1` instead of `www.foo.com/results/$1`.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Don't suppose I could get you to give me a 30 second spiel on why yours works and mine doesn't, eh?  (I'm still going to mark your answer as correct, either way.)